# Mysql database search through php and android

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, wamp

I've been working on a basic WAMP database test app for a bit and I am having a huge problem. I have managed to access all the data, add new data, and even delete data on my MySQL db, all from my android app using php. At this point, though, whenever I add specifications to search for specific data, like username or id number, I get a error in my code I am unable to figure out.

To begin with, here is my JSONParser code:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    is = null;
    jObj = null;
    json = "";

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);   /////THIS WHERE THE ERROR POINTS TO
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            url += "?" + paramString;

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");

                Log.i("1 ", line);
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

The call to the JSONParser class comes from a separate Java class, which extends AsyncTask:

```
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_product_details.php", "GET", params);
```

Next is the PHP file I use to search for a specific items info:

```
<?php

require 'connect.php';

if(isset($_GET['pid'])){
    $pid = trim($_GET['pid']);

    if($people = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM products WHERE pid = ?")){
        $people->bind_param('i', $pid);
        $people->execute();

        $people->bind_result($pid, $name, $price, $desc, $created_at, $updated_at);

        $product = array();

        while($people->fetch()){
                $product["pid"] = $pid;
                $product["name"] = $name;
                $product["price"] = $price;
                $product["description"] = $desc;
                $product["created_at"] = $created_at;
                $product["updated_at"] = $updated_at;
        }

        $response["success"] = 1;

        $response["product"] = array();
        $response["product"] = $product;


        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

The PHP has been tested on the web browser numerous times and works great. But whenever I call to it using the Android App, there seems to be a failure because nothing is returned.

Next is my logCat info:

```
08-13 01:16:50.259    2764-2764/com.dev.zane.testserver I/url﹕ http://10.0.2.2/UnCorkd/android_connect/get_product_details.php
08-13 01:16:50.259    2764-2764/com.dev.zane.testserver I/url﹕ http://10.0.2.2/UnCorkd/android_connect/get_product_details.php?pid=6
08-13 01:16:50.260    2764-2764/com.dev.zane.testserver D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-13 01:16:50.261    2764-2764/com.dev.zane.testserver E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dev.zane.testserver, PID: 2764
    android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
            at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
            at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
            at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
            at com.dev.zane.testserver.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:73)
            at com.dev.zane.testserver.EditProductActivity$GetProductDetails$1.run(EditProductActivity.java:131)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

The error seems to be on the line in the JSONParser class: 'HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);' under the GET section.

What could be causing this error? Is there some formatting or confusion between GET/POST?

Any help would be awesome guys, as I've been tearing my hair out for a couple days over this and can't seem to find any clear answers anywhere online. If I'm missing any info or you need more I'll be more then happy to add/edit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perform the network operations on separate thread.
You can use  an `AsyncTask` for this purpose. As your Log says you are performaing the network operation on the main thread.

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Place this code in `doInBackground()` method of `AsycTask`

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(                            "http://10.0.2.2/android_connect/get_product_details.php", "GET", params);
```

from s

Comment: As I mentioned above, the operation is already in an AsyncTask class. So it is called asynchronously already. Thank you though